# jQuery add class to active tab parent element

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery that is displaying content when a div is clicked...

```
<ul>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjj70qjk/

It is working great, what i want to do now though is add a class to the li for whichever tab is active so that I can style it.  I have this...

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery( function() {
    jQuery(".link").click(function() {
      if( jQuery( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
         return;
      }

      jQuery(".link").removeClass( 'active' );
      jQuery( this.parentNode ).addClass( 'active' );

      jQuery('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
});
```

Which is working but it doesn't remove the class, where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the class from its parent

```js
//no need to have $(document).ready(fn) and $(fn), they are the same
jQuery(function ($) {
  var $links = $(".link").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      return;
    }

    $links.parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this.parentNode).addClass('active');

    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + jQuery(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.active .link {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content-container">
  <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
  <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
  <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
  <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
  <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line:

```
jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
```

instead of :

```
jQuery(".link").removeClass( 'active' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing class from .link

```
 jQuery(".link").removeClass( 'active' );
```

but you are adding class to its parent

```
 jQuery( this.parentNode ).addClass( 'active' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.parentNode` to only `this`. That is what I did in your example and I think it is the result you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjj70qjk/2/